# How to get chainId / network name / network id etc in hardhat?

Tags: javascript, hardhat, typescript

I'm looking to get the ID of the chain/network I'm running a script on in `hardhat`. How can I get the names and IDs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few ways to get the network/chain name/id. We are going to assume you are in a `script` that you'd like to run, or a `test`. When running these, you must have a `hardhat.config.ts` or `hardhat.config.js`, and you must be running the script "in" hardhat. For example: `npx hardhat run scripts/your_script_here.ts`

```
import hre from 'hardhat'
const networkName = hre.network.name
const chainId = hre.network.config.chainId
```

This means, you'll need a hardhat.config that looks something like:

```js
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    defaultNetwork: 'hardhat',
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY!],
        },
```

You could also create a file that has a mapping between your network/chain name and ID.

Alternatively, you could use [hardhat-deploy](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy) with something like:

```js
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from 'hardhat/types'
import { DeployFunction } from 'hardhat-deploy/types'
const deployScript: DeployFunction = async function (
  hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment
) {
  const { getChainId } = hre
  const chainId = await getChainId()
```

Combined with a network mapping.

Comment: Hi, big fan thanks for ur videos :) could you please do a video or tutorial or blog article to explain the new gas system in ethereum and how to configure it correctly inside a transaction in hardhat or ethers. It was very simple before London fork.. now it is not :(

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it that works for me is

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const network = await ethers.getDefaultProvider().getNetwork();
console.log("Network name=", network.name);
console.log("Network chain id=", network.chainId);
```

As with the accepted answer, you must be running "in" Hardhat for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Add your network to networks section in hardhat config file:

```
networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    polygon: {
      url: JSON_RPC_URL, // Alchemy/Infura/QuickNode,...
      chainId: 137, // optional,
      accounts: [YOUR_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY] // optional
    }
}
```

then in your scripts to get chainId as hex string:

```
import { network } from 'hardhat';
const chainIdHex = await network.provider.send('eth_chainId');
```